# use setTimeout on a user interaction, but execute it only once

Tags: javascript

I have a button that is supposed to work in the following way:

When a user presses this button,`setTimeout` is called to wait a few seconds, and then execute a function.

Simplified, the code is as follows, were `onButtonClick` is called when the user presses the button:

```
function onButtonClick() {
  // executes some trivial things
  setTimeout(foo, 3000);
} 

function foo() {
  // do something
}
```

This works, however, the user is allowed (and even supposed to) click the button multiple times. Unintendedly,  foo will, after waiting 3 seconds, be executed multiple times. Instead, I only wish `foo` to be executed 3 seconds after the last button click.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout` to cancel `setTimeout`.

That way whenever the user click the button again, the last timeout is canceled and the new timeout begins.

```js
let timeout;

function onButtonClick() {
  // executes some trivial things
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(foo, 3000);
}

function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onButtonClick()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Depending on the context, you might also want to embed `timeout` into the `onButtonClick()` function object. i.e. `clearTimeout(onButtonClick.timeout); onButtonClick.timeout = setTimeout(foo, 3000);`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. From w3schools: `The clearTimeout()` method clears a timer set with the `setTimeout()` method. The ID value returned by `setTimeout()` is used as the parameter for the `clearTimeout()` method.